# SVG text size gradient

Tags: svg

I read the tutorial about gradients in SVG at http://www.svgbasics.com/text2.html. I was impressed by the Text fill and stroking part. It used a gradient defined to display text in a shaded manner. I was just wondering, can I change the size of the text using this gradient. Please give me an example of how to do this in a single tspan element.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the tspan elements with CSS, if you want to change the font-size that can be done e.g like this:

```
<style>
 tspan { font-size: 48px }
</style>
```

or alternatively using the corresponding presentation attribute:

```
<text>...<tspan font-size="48">big text</tspan>...</text>
```

Comment: I donot want to write a seperate tspan for each font size. E.g I want to use first alphabet of the first word of a para in size 20, and rest of it in size 20. It would mean that I will have to define two tspans, one for the Big first alphabet, and another for the rest of the text.

Comment: You can set a font-size on the `<text>` element too, and use `<tspan>` to override the font-size for the first word only.